# How do i enable DNSSEC on NameSilo (using DS records form YDNS)

Tags: dnssec, domain-registrar, dynamic-dns

(First of all i am new to domains in general and DNSSEC).
I have tried to enable DNSSEC on NamesSilo for my domain.
I only have the ds records in plane text and don't know wich value has to be inserted where
They *look* like this:

```
33333 77 1 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999
33333 77 2 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
33333 77 4 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

(these nubers are placeholders same number means same value but the 1,2 and 4 are there in reality and the length of the values is also correct).
But in NameSilo i **have** to enter the following:

```
Digest: [text field]
Key Tag: [text field]
Digest Type: [dropdown select option]
Algorithm: [dropdown select option]
```

I don't know what those values stand for neither do i know where to insert them.
i have to use Namesilo because i can pay there in bitcoin without kyc verfification.
i have to use ydns because my ip isn't static and i use my domain for projects i host myself.
Help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, check and double-check that the `DS` record(s) you are working with correspond the correct keys that are used to sign the zone (or sign the keys that sign the zone). Adding the `DS` record signals to everyone that the zone is signed with the corresponding key, and if that `DS` data is incorrect, the zone stops working at that point.

The order of the fields in the [`DS` record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4034.html#section-5) data is:

```
<keytag> <algorithm> <digesttype> <digest>
```

In the question you show having multiple `DS` records, but practically at this time what you really want to add is most likely just the digest type 2 (SHA256) `DS` record.

The guidance for choosing DNSSEC algorithms in [RFC8624](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8624#section-3) (from 2019, still of value at this time) covers both recommended `DNSKEY` algorithms as well as `DS` algorithms.
(Short version: `DS`: almost certainly 2/SHA256, `DNSKEY`: probably 13/ECDSAP256SHA256, or maybe 15/ED25519, or maybe 8/RSASHA256)

As for the registrar-provided interface for adding a `DS` record, the details will vary by registrar. Using the fields as mentioned in the question, I took the current `com` `DS` just to have an example with real values to work with:

```
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
```

That would translate to your fields in the question as:

- Digest: E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
- Key Tag: 30909
- Digest Type: 2
  (2 translates to SHA-256, see the [relevant registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ds-rr-types/ds-rr-types.xhtml) for this parameter)
- Algorithm: 8
  (8 translates to RSA/SHA-256, see the [relevant registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-sec-alg-numbers/dns-sec-alg-numbers.xhtml) for this parameter)